# Mic doesn't close by itself while practicing Speech Recognition in python

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, speech-recognition, spyder

I am trying to use my microphone for converting speech to text and print an output at the end. For some reason it is not detecting anything and not giving me an output either. Can someone spot why isn't working?

The code that I am using is

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Bro say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("You precious words are: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

In the beginning mic was detecting everything that I said but after 3-4 hours when I run it again,it doesn't work.

Comment: I'd say that you should check your hardware and/or revert back to your old code that was working. Don't think its a program issue if it was working initially. Any error raised?